# Token reset - bot has connected to Discord more than 1000 times within a short time period

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

my bot keeps reset token after one day of running.

It's very simple bot and runs on 5 servers where together there are about 300 members. Any ideas why?

```
require('dotenv').config();
const { Client, IntentsBitField, EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const PREFIX = process.env.PREFIX;
const COLOR = process.env.COLOR;
const PCOLOR = parseInt(COLOR, 16);

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMembers,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildModeration,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildEmojisAndStickers,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildIntegrations,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildWebhooks,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildInvites,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildVoiceStates,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildPresences,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessageReactions,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessageTyping,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.DirectMessages,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.DirectMessageReactions,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.DirectMessageTyping,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.MessageContent,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildScheduledEvents,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.AutoModerationConfiguration,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.AutoModerationExecution,
  ],
});

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Bot jest gotowy!`);
  console.log(`Informacje o serwerach:`);
  client.guilds.cache.forEach((guild) => {
    console.log(`- Nazwa serwera: ${guild.name}`);
    console.log(`  ID serwera: ${guild.id}`);
    console.log(`  Liczba członków: ${guild.memberCount}`);
  });
});

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (message.content.length >= 1000) return;
try{
  if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(PREFIX)){
    if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(PREFIX + 'help') || message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(PREFIX + 'pomoc')) {
      const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setColor(PCOLOR)  
      .setTitle('Uwaga! Śmieszne rzeczy!')
      .addFields(
      {
        name: 'Awatar',
        value: PREFIX + 'avatar @mention',
        inline: false,
      },
      );
      message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
      return;
    }

    if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(PREFIX + 'avatar')) {
      if (message.content.length >= 200) return;
      const mentionedUsers = message.mentions.users;
      if (mentionedUsers.size > 0) {
        const firstMentionedUser = mentionedUsers.first();
        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setColor(PCOLOR)
        .setDescription(`Awatar użytkownika ${firstMentionedUser}`)
        .setImage(firstMentionedUser.avatarURL() + '?size=1024');
        message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
      }
      else {
        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setColor(PCOLOR)
        .setDescription(`Awatar użytkownika ${message.author}`)
        .setImage(message.author.avatarURL() + '?size=1024');
        message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
      }
      return;
    }
  }

  if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes('uod')) {
    message.react('');
    message.react('');
  }

  if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes('conga')) {
    message.reply('<a:conga:1109250474982506630>');
  }
  
  if (message.content.toLowerCase() === ('wow') || message.content.toLowerCase().includes(':0')) {
    message.reply('https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1108404891145220268/1108405967344893992/wow.mov');
    return;
  }

  if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes('idk') || message.content.toLowerCase().includes('nie wiem')) {
    message.reply('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1108404891145220268/1108405993471225896/idk.mp4');
    return;
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Wystąpił błąd:', error);
}
});

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

> Hey nielot, It appears your bot, X, has connected to Discord more than 1000 times within a short time period. Since this kind of behavior is usually a result of a bug we have gone ahead and reset your bot's token. Obtain a New Bot Token:

I can't find one solution on the internet. Some guy had same problem but he had client.login in function. Any ideas/help?

Comment: Where do you host your bot?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to mind is either:

1. You somehow leaked the token and its being used by someone else at the same time (this should be fixed if you just start using the new token which I assume you tried already).
2. Your bot is crashing and starting up right after that. This could be the result of a bug in your code and hosting the bot on `pm2` which starts it back up after it crashes in any way.

I also noticed that you are not using any async functionality. I don't know if this is intentional but as far as I know, when you user `message.reply('message')` you need to put `await` before it and apply `async` to the function you use `await` in.

I hope I gave you some idea of what to do next but I do admit. it is a strange problem.